# Spring JPA Criteria API - search occurrences in relations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have 3 entities:

```
User(id, first_name etc)
Message(id, name, user_id) - messages sent for user
Event(id, event_name, message_id) - events in message ex. click, open etc.
```

I use Criteria API for searching user objects by dynamic filters. In fronted application user can chose any entity parameter (as first_name), operation (as EQUALS) and value (as. "John") to specify predictions to return users.

Defined:

```
Root<User> root = ....
```

I created ExpressionInterpreter and equals method for single Entity.

```
public static <T> Predicate equals(Root<T> root,
                                       CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
                                       CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery,
                                       IExpression expression) {

        if(expression.getKey().getType().equals(USER)) {
            return criteriaQuery
                    .select(root)
                    .where(
                            criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                    root.get(expression.getKey()),
                                    expression.getValue()
                            )
                    )
                    .getRestriction();
        }
```

I would like to search users by specific event_name from Event entity. I would like to return users for whom the event occurred or not occurred for message. So I would like to build prediction thats prepare sql as below:

```
select distinct u
       from user u 
       join message m on m.user_id = u.id
       join event e on e.message_id = m.id
       where (
            exists (
                select 1
                from event e
                where e.event_name = 'event_name_example' and e.message_id = m.id
            )
       )
```

Maybe it can be done more simply.
How to build this Predicate by Criteria API?

Comment: You don't need to build the criteriaQuery with a select and where class just to return a predicate - just return criteriaBuilder.equal(..) in your method. criteriaBuilder.exists also returns a predicate, and there are many examples showing how to build a sub query (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Subquery_examples )

Comment: @Chris i must use predicates because I build expressions with filters. I can define combined filters (ex. user.id = 1 and Event.name = 'test')

Comment: Not sure what that has do do with having to call .select(root). where(...).getRestriction(). You can just return the criteriaBuilder.equal(..) as it is a predicate and will result in the same predicate being returned. You are modifying the pass in query though, potentially add in different 'select' operations to the query which seems wrong if you are only trying to build predicates